# SVD for Non-Square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, svd

Is QR decomposition a pre-requisite for SVD decompostion of non-square matrices? I have been unable to find a clear cut answer to this question. I will be grateful for a response.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is whether in order to compute the singular value decomposition of a given matrix, one needs to compute QR decompositions I believe the answer is no. One can use them to this end but they are not necessary, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Calculating_the_SVD).

Answer (score 0):

The pedantic answer is no.  As an example, the one-sided Jacobi-Hestenes method does not require the QR-factorisation.

However, the standard methods (see Example the textbook, "Matrix Computations" by Gene Golub and Charles Van Loan),  contains the the following three steps. We assume
that the $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is real and $m \ge n$. Otherwise, work with the transpose of $A$.

Step 1: Reduce the $m \times n$ matrix $A$ to the triangular form by QR-factorization.  That is, $A = QR$ where $R$ is a $n \times n$  (upper) triangular matrix.
Step 2: Reduce the matrix $R$ to the bidiagonal matrix $B$ using orthogonal transformations. $U^tRV = B$ where $U^tU = V^tV = I$.
Step 3: Compute the SVD of the bidiagonal matrix $B$ using any standard method. These include, 
(a) QR-algorithm, (b) bisection and (c) divide and conquer.

Since $B$ has only $2n-1$ elements, the SVD problem of $B$ is rather easy to handle compared with the $m \times n$ matrix $A$. As an example,  if $m$ is $10,000$ and $n$ is $10$ then the reduction in complexity is staggering.
Instead of working with $100,000$ elements we are playing with $21$ elements.